# What is the difference between animate and setInterval in my case

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div id="answer" style="width:100px;height:50px;">Answer></div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var answer = $('#answer');
    var sizeChangerHandle;

    function setBackground() {
        sizeChangerHandle = setInterval(changeConstantly, 1);
    }


    function changeConstantly() {

        answerHeight = answer.height();
        answerWidth = answer.width();
        answer.width(answerWidth + 1);
        answer.height(answerHeight + 1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            clearInterval(sizeChangerHandle);
        }, 300)

        // I am only using one of these codes, either the above or the below! I comment the other one out when I use one.
        answer.animate({
            width: 400,
            height: 200
        }, 300);

    }

    setBackground();
});
```

I am trying to widen my DIV from being 100px wide to 400px wide and to have this take 300 split seconds. When I use the animate function, it works perfectly. The Div ends up 400px wide and it takes 300 split seconds. When I use the Intervals, the DIV stops its width at 176px. Why is this, it should really be running for 300 split seconds?

Comment: There's probably some overhead to calling `.height()`, `.width()`, etc. and that takes about a millisecond to complete each time, causing your `clearInterval` to fire before the 300 function calls could be completed.

Comment: @Blender  thanks, how can i check if this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `changeConstantly` interval is not really firing once every millisecond. From MDN's notes on [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting):

> Historically browsers implement `setTimeout` "clamping": successive `setTimeout` calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit are forced to the use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay, `DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE`, is **4 ms**...

The MDN page on [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval#Notes) confirms that this 4 millisecond restriction applies to `setInverval` as well.

Therefore, your interval function only runs 75 times (300 ms divided by 4 ms inverval), rather than 300 times. (Or, maybe it runs 76 times -- the last interval probably gets run just before the interval is cleared.)

The solution is to rewrite your code using an interval delay of no less than `4`, and make your `<div>` grow by 4 times more during each iteration, i.e., use `answer.height(answerHeight + 4);`.

Comment: Brilliant, answer fits my 176px perfectly. Very clever! +1